# Regex: Return value can match or be empty

Tags: .net, regex

How can I change the following regular expression to make empty values (a.k.a String.Empty) also match:

```
^[0-9]{4}$
```

I've tried the following but have had no success:

```
^[0-9]{4}$|^$
(^[0-9]{4}$)*
```

I'm using a VB.Net Application and comparing with the namespace *System.Text.RegularExpressions*.

Note:  The regular expression is a four-digit number representing the last four of an SSN; and it is optional.  Therefore, I would like to resolve the match with one regular expression than have to do something like this:

```
If myString.Length = 0 Then
   'This is Ok
Else
   'Do the regular expression comparison here
End if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
^[0-9]{0,4}$
```

It'll match the input having 0-4 digits.

If you only want 0 or 4 digits, use this:

```
^[0-9]{4}$|^$
```

Demo: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=cd85169b-f5f8-457e-8f8e-759816213fb5

Comment: He says he's already tried the second statement. Although I don't know why it wouldn't have worked. Does the | operator work in VB regular expressions?

Comment: Hmmm... I tried with a .Net engine and it works. See my edit.

Comment: Ok...maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet.  I tried ^[0-9]{4}$|^$ again and it worked.  I must have incorrectly tested it earlier.  Marking as answer.  Ty for help.

Comment: @Mrchief  One more question:  as a general rule of thumb, does adding "|^$" make it optional?

Comment: The `|` is the `OR` operator. So you're saying match LHS _Or_ RHS. Since you have an empty pattern on RHS, this works. Optional per se is achieved by using `?` (0 or one) or `*` (0 or more).

Answer (score 1):

This would do it: `^([0-9 ]{4})?$`

Comment: ty for the answer.  This made me realize my question was poorly worded.  I didn't mean blanks as in ASCII value 32.  I meant an empty value altogether.  (String.Empty)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following regex:

```
^([0-9]{4})?$
```

Hope this helps.